Looking for name of a very old short cartoon
So I'm looking for an old short cartoon I used to watch on Cartoon Network in the early-90's. The cartoon was one of those stand alone, independent pieces, and it felt and looked like "Symphony in Slang" (1951).
There was a narrator telling the story, there weren't any dialogues. It was about a guy who falls in love with a woman, but she's richer than him and he tries to do everything he can to impress her, but he's always outdone by this richer dude. An example I remember is once, he brings her a diamond ring, and she uses a magnifying glass to look at it. Then she puts goggles on her and his face and shows him the rock that the jock guy gave her, and how big it is and how brightly it shines. 
The end is that the guy is super depressed and he doesn't get the girl.
Any ideas?

I think it's a Tom and Jerry short called "Blue Cat Blues"(1956). 
Because of its tragicness and the implied suicide at the end, the cartoon was aired very few times on TV.
Tom sees a beautiful white female cat and is immediately smitten. However he has a much wealthier rival for her attention (Butch). The female cat is a opportunist (re:gold digger) and leaves Tom for Butch. Jerry knows the female is a gold digger, and trys to warn Tom, but Tom ignores Jerry's warning and pushes himself and his finances to the limit trying to win the female feline's attention with presents such as flowers, perfume, diamond rings, and a car, but the cat rejects all of his efforts, as Butch's presents are much bigger, more expensive, and much more outrageously extravagant (including a tanker truck full of perfume, a ring with a diamond so large and shiny that it cannot be looked at without eye protection, and getting into Butch's more luxurious coupe).
Now broken-hearted, penniless, and deep in debt, Tom tries to drown his sorrows in milk, deaf to Jerry's pleas to stop. Tom is about to literally let himself go down the gutter until Jerry, at the last second, rescues him. Just when Tom's life could not get any worse, he sees that his ex-girlfriend is now Butch's wife; the pair drive past him in a car with a "Just Married" sign on the back.
Of course, then Jerry's girlfriend drives by with another mouse and a "Just Married" sign. So both Tom and Jerry sit depressed on the railroad tracks as a train approaches.
Clip of the full short (the ring scene starts around 4:00):
https://vimeo.com/93815930

Women......  ;o)

@JohnnyBones I feel slightly insulted. ^_^

4 months is a long time to go without being insulted by me.  Just ask anyone on my Facebook.  :oD

This one is infamous for its super dark ending. They don't make cartoons like that anymore!
